# Update de un campo con el resultado de un select que devuelve varios registros PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

Debo realizar una consulta que sume los precios agrupados por varios conceptos, luego, insertar esos resultados en la columna de totales, solo cuando la cantidad es distinta de 0.

Sería así:

```
Precio  Departamento    Unidad  Mes Cantidad_item
3              a          1     ene     1
2              a          1     ene     0
12             a          1     feb     1
10             a          1     feb     0
1              a          2     mar     1
8              a          2     mar     0
```

Es decir, se realiza un `select sum precio group by departamento, unidad, mes` etc.

Hasta ahí fantástico. Lo que no sé es cómo lograr que los resultados de cada grupo se inserten en la fila de totales donde la cantidad de `items` de cada grupo es distinto de 0 (cuando realizo las agrupaciones, solo queda un registro donde cantidad es distinto de 0)

Debería quedar algo así:

```
Precio  Departamento    Unidad  Mes Cantidad_item   Total
3   a   1   ene 1   5
2   a   1   ene 0   
12  a   1   feb 1   22
10  a   1   feb 0   
1   a   2   mar 1   9
8   a   2   mar 0
```

Comment: hola puedes mandarnos un ejemplo del codigo que lleves ahorita para ver mas o menos lo que estas intentando hacer :)

Comment: el problema principal de esto es.. el total esta en la misma tabla?? porque a que registro le vas a poner el total? cual es la clave unica del registro como para poner el total?

Answer (score 1):

No queda claro qué quieres decir con insertar esos resultados en una columna de totales pero por el resultado que esperas, entiendo que lo que pretendes es una select que te agrupe la información, calcule el total y filtre dejando únicamente los registros que tienen cantidad distinta de 0.

Necesitarás una consulta que agrupe, calcule y además filtre sobre el resultado de la agrupación:

```
SELECT precio,
       departamento,
       unidad,
       mes,
       sum(cantidad_item),
       sum(cantidad_item) * precio
  FROM nombre_de_la_tabla
 GROUP BY precio,
          departamento,
          unidad,
          mes
HAVING sum(cantidad_item) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Con WHERE puedes crear condiciones como esas haciendo un WHERE NOT (cantidad_item=0)
select sum precio WHERE NOT cantidad_item=0 group by departamento, unidad, mes, cantidad_item 
Busca Mas Información en Internet en la w3schools si quieres mas info que esta.

SELECT precio,
       departamento,
       unidad,
       mes,
       sum(cantidad_item),
       sum(cantidad_item) * precio
  FROM nombre_de_la_tabla
 GROUP BY precio,
          departamento,
          unidad,
          mes
WHERE NOT (cantidad_item = 0)
HAVING sum(cantidad_item) > 0

Comment: Cada caso es Particular Ya que no se sabe nunca los nombres que se les pone a las variables